# How to handle pdf when downloading a raw pdf file from sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, http, pdf, stored-procedures, encoding

I can download small text-only pdf files from stored procedure, but complex pdf files look to be truncated. I'm reading the resultText into a table that is varchar(max) so not sure why large files are cut off. Is there a way around this?

MSSQL stored procedure calling a URL to download pdf, @WorkingURI is a pdf file that is 2 pages, but small size. @NotWorkingURI is being cut off.

```
declare
@WorkingURI      varchar(100),
@NotWorkingURI   varchar(100)

CREATE TABLE #ResponseMax
(
    MaxString           VARCHAR(MAX)
)

SET @WorkingURI = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'
SET @NotWorkingURI = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf'

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, 'GET', @NotWorkingURI,'false', NULL, NULL

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml'

-- send the request 

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, '' 

declare @statusText varchar(1000), @status varchar(1000) 

-- Get status text

exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText', @statusText out
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status', @status out

select @status, @statusText

INSERT INTO #ResponseMax ( MaxString ) 
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText'

select *
from #ResponseMax
```

Depending on the pdf file, sometimes I get the full pdf, complete with the "%%EOF" at the end of the responseText, and sometimes I get a string that looks like it's truncated with special characters that resembles a binary string (but is not complete). It seems to have something to do with the size of the file.